# Cheaper in absolute sense to buy more?

Tags: scams, contracts

I recently talked to my ISP. I am paying ~80 USD/mo for telephone service. If I purchase DSL + telephone service, other than a one off equipment charge I will pay ~60 USD/mo total. This without any contract other than month to month. I don't see anything in the terms saying I have to use either service a set amount or anything, just pay the bill by the due date. Am I missing something? This seems to be "too good to be true".

Response to comments: There are limits on instantaneous rates, but rather generous ones. I do not see anything about billing cycle rates. I checked the ISP's pricing signed out and via proxy. The price I would be getting is the same as advertised.

Comment: Is the ISP unlimited bandwidth? Internet phone is almost free and usually long distance is very, very cheap. There might be some small additional charge or issue with 911 service.

Comment: You might also be on a grandfathered-in contract with higher prices - have you checked their current prices for new customers for the same package you have at the moment?

Answer (score 2):

The obvious suggestion is to read the terms of the agreement very carefully.  And then read them again.  :->)

Cable companies always run bundled deals.  In most cases, for the basics, they are cheaper than the buying the individual components.

I get cable TV through my Homeowner's Association.  I am paying for it but through my HOA fees.  I add a small upgrade channel package that provides some like  BBC, Bloomberg TV, etc.  For many years I purchased DSL and home line from a different provider because in my area, DSL is more reliable than my other choices.

18 months ago I picked up a bundled package that includes everything that I was paying out of pocket for (not the HOA) for $40 less a month.  So while I'm still paying for cable TV via the HOA dues, it's cheaper to pay for everything elsewhere. It seems to be "too good to be true" but it is true.

And to add another "too good to be true" moment, when my house was built, for some reason that I don't understand, the  new cable TV provider  can only reach 2 rooms and the original HOA provider is in all of the other rooms so I have both  available in my house.  It's not that I watch that much TV but there are some channels on each provider that the other doesn't offer. Win win.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than go into details of specific packages, let's consider two things: 1) the overall trend in computing and communications technology, and 2) the desire of service providers to make as much profit as possible from their customers.

Both computing speed-and-capacity and communications speed-and-capacity have been improving rapidly throughout their histories and costs have been coming down. The trends continue.

A service provider -- be it phone, TV or internet -- signs a customer up for whatever great deal they can come up with *at that time*. It compares favorably with the competition. The customer continues to pay for the particular service, for the particular rate, perhaps forever.

Every few months/years or so, because of the trends (point 1 above) -- and perhaps because of the economies of scale of signing up more and more customers -- the service provider is easily able to offer much better value-for-money deals ... but only offers them to *new* customers. The existing customers continue to pay the old rates for the old service. It is not in its financial interest for the service provider to automatically upgrade existing customers to the better deals. (A particularly odious exception to this rule is when the service provider automatically "upgrade" existing customers to *more expensive* packages.)

I have noticed this practice personally, with TV, phone and internet packages. The good news is that existing customers -- unless they've signed a multi-year deal -- can always renegotiate a better deal. It behooves customers to annually monitor the *current* deals-for-new-customers offered by service providers, compare them with their existing deal, and, if necessary, demand a new deal.

Answer (score 1):

It's not uncommon, the only thing to watch out for are monthly fees that aren't part of the bottom line, nor government mandated.

For example, Comcast sells a cable internet + basic cable TV package in my area for significantly less than the cable internet alone, but the package has broadcast and regulatory compliance fees, etc which are pure profit to Comcast.  These also aren't covered by the price lock-in guarantee.

[image]

Here you can see mine add to over $12/month.  For packages which include the sports coverage surcharge, the total can easily be over $20.

The package you describe doesn't have TV channels, but it does include phone, so watch out for surcharges such as "peering", "E-911 registration", "listing in phone book", and so on.

So **make sure you are comparing the final monthly price, not the base price**.  But it is likely that the bundle still wins, at least for as long as you are receiving an introductory rate.

Answer (score 0):

Actual DSL over the original copper phone lines is unusual in major metros. The internet service would not be very good but the phone service would be good quality as long as the original phone lines are supported.

If the internet service were over the cable TV lines then phone service, without an adapter, is possible to an actual internet-phone and that through an independent VOIP provider at very low cost. The quality of VOIP in general is not as good as the original phone lines.

Basically, most any VOIP service that provides a phone adapter is an expensive service. Otherwise an internet-phone, with an ethernet plug but without an adapter, can be set-up through a router that accepts ethernet plug-in.

Comment: VoIP phone adapters are not expensive, and do not require special service.

Comment: In general, the affordable VOIP services work to an internet-phone that has an ethernet plug. The internet-phone requires setup to the chosen VOIP service provider. The internet-phone plugs into a router.  A VOIP service that provides adapters and setup is usually a very expensive service by the month. Well, I pay about $5 a month for VOIP service to an internet-phone.

Comment: So buy your own adapter and use any VoIP service supporting standard protocols.  Having someone else do it all for you is of course expensive, just like paying a computer store to install Windows updates for you.  It's wasteful and not necessary.  Adapters marketed for DIY setup even provide a wizard with presets for common providers.

Comment: To setup an internet-phone, it's necessary to go to the phone's website. The internet-phone setups like a computer. Instructions for the setup are required from the chosen VOIP service provider. Some VOIP systems will work with adapters but proprietary systems require a proprietary adapter.

Comment: Yes, I have one.  Cost about $40 for the adapter hardware.  Have to replace the adapter with a new model every 3-5 years to keep up with service encryption upgrades.  So that makes VoIP through adapter roughly $1/month more than with a softphone (and substantially cheaper than an Ethernet phone, which will also need periodic upgrades).

Comment: So basically I was saying that a proprietary internet phone service requires a proprietary phone adapter but then provides the adapter while charging an expensive monthly fee for the overall service.

Comment: I'm sure it is possible to overpay.  My comment was simply intended to inform readers that they can save money by getting their adapter and service separately.

Answer (score 0):

You may be overpaying for your phone service currently.  I would expect phone service to cost [$30](https://electronics.costhelper.com/phone-line.html) alone and DSL to be in the $50-60 range.  A bundle of $60 is on the low side but not ridiculously so (I found a $50 deal on Google).  Remember that most of their costs are line maintenance.  The first connection is what's expensive.  Once you've made it, their costs don't increase that much for additional services.

$80 for phone is extremely high.

Comment: Even $30 seems rather high.  I dumped my land line years ago when it went over that.  (And cell service was under $10.)